# Firebase Analytics + GoogleTagManager Failure to convert a map's value to object: NULL

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I'm using GoogleTagManager to post Firebase events and screen views to Google Analytics. Everything is set to version 9.4.0 in build.gradle. I had a working GTM configuration and changed only a few things. Suddenly, the log shows this error message every time an event is fired (I stripped the log of timestamps):

```
V/GoogleTagManager: Executing: __ua
E/GoogleTagManager: Failure to convert a map's value to object: NULL (com.google.android.gms.internal.zzado)
E/GoogleTagManager: Internal error - Function call: __ua_main
                    null
```

Right after that, it shows `Log passthrough event ... to Firebase` as if everything's fine. I changed the configuration back to the previous one (both locally and live), but the error doesn't go away. Does anyone know what the error means? How to solve it? I can't find anything about it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting on the product forum was a good idea. A Google developer contacted me a few days later. Apparently, there was an issue in the user property variables that caused tags not to fire when there were no default values set. The issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

What are you specifically trying to track in this tag? How have you configured your tag? Are you still getting your data in Google Analytics?Generally speaking you the tag should still be firing.

You may also have more luck posting on the [product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/tag-manager).